# Embed windows 8 store app in a web application

Tags: web-applications, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm still new to Metro Style app technology , and would like to create a metro style app, that can be embedded in my web page. The same way we used to work with Silverlight . Wherever I search , I found frameworks to provide metro style UI design. But my question is whether it is possible to display an EXISTING windows 8 metro style app/control in web page.

My target is to create a portal to look like the new Windows Azure Portal

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Why the -1 vote?? Please, do comment if you have some critique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot embed a Windows Store app in a web browser.

Unlike Silverlight (or other plug-in based technologies such as Flash), a Windows Store app is an application that runs only on Windows 8.

You can certainly use HTML and CSS styles to replicate the look and feel of a Windows Store app in a website, but you should also take into account the differences between a website and an app, and provide the appropriate user experience for your users.

If your goal is to build something with a similar look and feel to the Windows Azure management portal, I would suggest examining the CSS styles used for that site. You can do this using the IE Developer Tools (press F12 while viewing the site) or Firebug or the Chrome Dev Tools. From a quick peek, it appears that the developers made significant use of jQueryUI, which is a good framework for adding rich UI functionality to your website.

Ultimately, though, you will need to develop the markup, scripts, and CSS to give you the look and feel you're looking for. As noted above, you cannot run a Windows Store app in a web browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think you are right about this. I searched everywhere for this , but seems like it is not doable.
The new presentation of the azure portal is so good , that it gave me the feel of a windows store app